# Content Disapearing from Mysql CMS

Tags: php, mysql, database, content-management-system

I built a custom CMS for a client allowing them to add news type articles. The system has worked great for the last 2 years but as of recently a majority of the posts information will randomly disappear. The title, author and other info remains but the news description and any hyperlinks within disappear. Any blink reactions on why this would happen?

Comment: you say `randomly disappear` does this mean its gone from the db or its just not showing up on the page?

Comment: [Crystal ball mode on:] Without having any changes on the code, this is very unlikely. Maybe someone hacked your database, or the editor-in-chief can't like you, or your intern is messing around…

Comment: It seems likes some of the content shifts locations. For example the news articles have a title, source, and description and often the source is listed in the description field when I want to edit the entry in the CMS and the description is missing. Would having special characters in a field cause content to shift tables?

Answer (score 0):

Try reviewing your code that generating the update sql queries on those fields, you may found a bug causing the wrong records to get updated